# Kubelet fails on Startup: could not detect clock speed from output: ""

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I'm currently building a containerized Kubernetes Cluster.

When trying to get start the kubelet binary I get this fail

```
server.go:233] failed to run Kubelet: could not detect clock speed from output: ""
```

I start the kubelet with

```js
/bin/kubelet \
--address 192.168.0.4 \
--allow-privileged true \
--anonymous-auth true \
--authorization-mode AlwaysAllow \
--cloud-provider ""\
--cni-bin-dir /opt/cni/bin \
--cni-conf-dir /etc/cni/net.d \
--containerized true \
--container-runtime remote \
--container-runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock \
--image-pull-progress-deadline 2m \
--kubeconfig /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
--network-plugin cni \
--register-node true \
--root-dir /var/lib/kubelet \
--v 2
```

Onto an alpine image. The image is run privileged.

Checking the corresponding sourcecode did not reveal the source of the issue.
Does someone have direction to point me to?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was adding a volume to link to the cgroup, so cadvisor had the required rights to read the required file.

```
-v /cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```